# Setting optimal value to lie in any of the given specified value

Tags: excel, optimization, solver, vba

I'm using open solver to solve an optimization problem. The problem is as follows:

Suppose I'm optimizing input with given total cost constraint and input availability. We have input cost and want to minimize the cost. The another constraint is the optimized input falls in any of the set value, say input11, input12, input13 and input14. This discrete input range varies across inputs.

So we have 3 constraints:

1. budget,
2. input capacity for each inputs and
3. inputs should fall within any of the falling four options.

The portion of the code I created:

```
Sub TestOpensolver()

Dim TestSheet As Worksheet
Set TestSheet = Worksheets("Optimized_Results")

    OpenSolver.ResetModel Sheet:=TestSheet

    'Objective Definition
    OpenSolver.SetObjectiveFunctionCell TestSheet.Range("AC3"), Sheet:=TestSheet
    OpenSolver.SetObjectiveSense MinimiseObjective, Sheet:=TestSheet

    'Variables Definition
    OpenSolver.SetDecisionVariables TestSheet.Range("AK3:AK8"), Sheet:=TestSheet
    OpenSolver.SetDecisionVariables TestSheet.Range("AQ3:AR8"), Sheet:=TestSheet

    ' Constraints       

    OpenSolver.AddConstraint TestSheet.Range("AK3:AK8"), RelationLE, TestSheet.Range("W3:W8"), Sheet:=TestSheet
    OpenSolver.AddConstraint TestSheet.Range("AK3:AK8"), RelationGE, TestSheet.Range("X3:X8"), Sheet:=TestSheet


    OpenSolver.AddConstraint TestSheet.Range("AS3:AS8"), RelationLE, TestSheet.Range("AT3:AT8"), Sheet:=TestSheet


    OpenSolver.RunOpenSolver , False



End Sub
```

Can anyone please help me to solve the problem?

Thank you!

Comment: No time to write up an answer, but I think [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41653105/excel-solver-finding-a-target-sum-from-subset-of-number-set/41658675#41658675) is very close to what you are trying to achieve, although it's not using opensolver.

Comment: @OldUgly: Thanks for your suggestion. I found some answer following your suggestion. But need some more testing. Also, it's not working in open solver. I need to run it on open solver as the optimization problem is large and excel solver can't solve it. But thanks again to show me the path!

Comment: Now this might sound like a quick hack but since you are running the solver from VBA you could run it separately for the four different equality constraints in a for loop and choose the best answer from the four.

Answer (score 0):

'or' conditions typically mean we need to use binary variables, e.g.:

```
input1 = input11*y11 + input12*y12 + input13*y13 + input14*y14
y11+y12+y13+y14 <= 1
y11,y12,y13,y14 binary variables
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But this is not I'm looking for. Suppose without the extra constraint, I'm getting value 10 for input1. But I want the optimized input1 either be 9 or 11 or 14 or 16. 10 is not an acceptable value. So input1 extra contraint be, should take any of [9, 11, 14, 16]. Hope I clarifies the question.

Comment: I'm new in solving optimization using solver. So even easier answers I find difficult to solve. I'm having hard time coding the answer you suggested. I'm updating what I've done so far. If you can help further. Thank you!

Comment: I think you missed that y are binary variables.

Comment: I'm running optimization on 2 set of variables, i) level ii) binary variables. So I put all binaries as 1 and put "sum_binary" less than "binary constant". Please let me know if I'm making mistake here

Comment: I have no clue what you are saying here. "Putting a variable as 1"? No idea what that means,

Comment: I mention the reason for "Putting a variable as 1" in the main question. I might be doing it wrongly. And I'm not getting example to implement it. So if you can point me to the right direction.